# Get the Whole Black Image When Using the TakesScreenshot in WebDriver Test with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

As the title mentioned above, I need to capture the browser screen using the TakesScreenshot class and save as the image file while running my WebDriver tests.

However, I got what I was expected in Firefox and IE browsers except the Chrome, which just created the whole black image.

Of course, I have searched for the solution several times but still not fixed it yet. Any idea with this problem?

Tools:
selenium-java-2.34.0.jar
ChromeDriver v2.2

Comment: Are you running this locally or remotely? Remotely being using TeamCity, Jenkins, some kind of CI server or even remotely connected to a server and running them? What version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: It runs locally with Chrome v28 and ChromeDriver v2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromedriver doesn't natively support taking screenshots, AFAIK.
You can do this either by Augmenting the driver, or by using the Robots class.

The first solution will lead to an image that shows what is currently visible on the screen, but not necessarily the entire page (if you have a really long webpage, it won't show the whole thing, like FF will).

The second solution isn't a selenium solution, but it will still work, and I believe it gets the entire page (I haven't actually tried this solution, as I prefer the first)

They are both described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/NLHXlhPrADs

Comment: I tried the second solution just now and it worked, although it captured the whole computer screen instead of the entire browser page as I expected. And also, I tried the first solution but it still returned the black images.